# react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view not scrolling on Android

Tags: react-native

I have a screen with multiple inputs. Right now, when I press one of the text inputs, the keyboard comes up and it covers the inputs. I tried to use `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` it works very well on iOS but unfortunately nothing happens on Android.

In my `AndroidManifest` under `Activity` tag I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`.

Also this is the code I use in my example:

```
class Login extends Component {
    public render() {
        return (
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            enableOnAndroid
            enableAutomaticScroll={(Platform.OS === 'ios')}
            contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}
            extraHeight={130}>

                <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
                        <View style={styles.inner}>
                            <Text style={styles.header}>
                                Header
                            </Text>
                            <TextInput
                                placeholder="Username"
                                style={styles.input}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                                placeholder="Password"
                                style={styles.input}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                                placeholder="Confrim Password"
                                style={styles.input}
                            />
                            <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
                                <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => null} />
                            </View>
                            {/* <View style={{ flex : 1 }} /> */}
                            <View style={{ height: 60 }} />
                        </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </SafeAreaView>
                </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
            // </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    inner: {
        padding: 24,
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
    },
    header: {
        fontSize: 36,
        marginBottom: 48,
    },
    input: {
        height: 40,
        borderColor: "#000000",
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 36,
    },
    btnContainer: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        marginTop: 12,
    },
});

export default Login;
```

I also tried to use `KeyboardAvoidingView`.

My `react-native` version is **0.63.3**

Answer (score 1):

give height to safe area view style using dimensions it will work

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const window = Dimensions.get('window');

<View style={{ height: (window.height) * 1 }}></View>
```

for your question  give a height for container like below,

```
container: {
    height: (window.height) * 1
},
```

Comment: Do you mean something like that?
`height:Dimensions.get('screen').height`

Comment: So I should put `<View style={{ height: (window.height) * 1 }}></View>` instead of `SafeArea` line?

Comment: no give height to safe area  "height: (window.height) * 1", @Keselme see edited answer